# SVN Could not open password file

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server

I installed VisualSVN Server and added 1 Repo as a test. When I try to Checkout on my local machine I get this error

```
Command: Checkout from ..../svn/testtt/trunk, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL  
Error:  '.../svn/testtt/trunk'  
Error: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/testtt/trunk'
```

When I opened the log file I found this error

```
AH01620: Could not open password file: .../Repo/htpasswd
(OS 5) Access is denied.  
[client 53.248.242.196]
```

Although the htpasswd contains the user I've created.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Access is denied.`, and it means that the account that runs the VisualSVNServer service (HTTP service) does not have permissions to the `htpasswd` file.

By default, VisualSVN Server services run under `Network Service` account, so you should ensure that it has all the necessary permissions to read and modify your repositories folder. See the article [KB37: Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/) for general information on the required permission configuration.